# java.sql.SQLException: The column position '1' is out of range

Tags: java, sqlexception

I have this error and I do not understand it, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

java.sql.SQLException: The column position '1' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '0'.

```
public Object[][] searchFunction(String searchWord, String loginId) {
    Object[][] data = new Object[5][6];
    String[] tableName = {"subject", "sender", "recipient", "label", "message"};
    int nr = 0, i = 0, q = 1;
    boolean hasRows = false;
    for(int j = 0; j<5; j++) {
        try {    
            PreparedStatement prepareStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender = ? AND " + tableName[j] + " LIKE '%Done%' ORDER BY id ASC");    
            prepareStatement.setString(1, loginId);     
            rs = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                hasRows = true;
                boolean check = true;
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                int priority = rs.getInt("priority");
                String recipient = rs.getString("recipient");
                String labelDb = rs.getString("label");
                String subject = rs.getString("subject");    
                String date = rs.getString("date");    
                String stars = setPriorityStars(priority);

                for(int k=0; k<i+1; k++) {
                    Object idObj = (Integer) id;
                    if(data[k][0] == idObj) check = false; 
                }

                if(check == true) {
                        data[i][0] = q;
                        data[i][1] = stars;
                        data[i][2] = recipient;
                        data[i][3] = labelDb;
                        data[i][4] = subject;
                        data[i][5] = date;
                        i++;
                        nr++;
                        q++;
                    }

            }
            if(hasRows == false) {
            data = getInbox(loginId);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no fields that includes " + searchWord);
            break;
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Found " + nr + " results");
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is here

```
 prepareStatement.setString(1, loginId);
```

In your query you don't have `?`to set this value. Change your query respect to loginid or remove this line if login id doesn't mean anything

Answer (score 0):

It may be telling you that that value in the loginId String is longer than the database column named sender that you are comparing it to in the where clause.

Also, your code as written will leak a lot of memory because you are not closing your PreparedStatement before you create a new one in the next iteration of your loop.